# Evee and Workbench use Gpu when rendering but Cycles doesn't

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

For some reason when I use the Cycles to render something it wont use my Gpu. I already changed it in my prefferences so I could use my graphics card. I have anA MD Ryzen 7 4800u graphics card and use Blender 2.83. But I also had this prolem with an older computer. What can I do tofix this problem?

[image]

Comment: The AMD Ryzen 7 is a CPU, not a graphics card like you said.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't shure about it

Comment: Its fine. So the thing is, most CPUs have an integrated GPU to help run the operating system, display stuff, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Eric Xue, the Ryzen 7 4800u is a CPU with only integrated graphics. Unless you have a dedicated graphics card, i.e nVidia Geforce RTX, or AMD Radeon, you cannot use the GPU render function because Blender does not render on integrated graphics.

Your GPU rendering selection is grayed out, signifying that you do not have a GPU or a  non-compatible GPU.

If you do have a compatible nVidia or AMD GPU, enable it in the Blender Preferences.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't shuere about thus whole gpu thing myself. But why do Evee and workbench use the GPU? Sorry uf the question is stupid.

Comment: If you are checking the task manager for GPU usage, Blender uses the integrated graphics for processing 3D objects, but not rendering. When you are rendering in EEVEE or Workbench, it may show up in the task manager that the GPU is being used a bit, because it is being used to process the objects.